# namspacing in Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, autoloader

I have a question. I'm using **Laravel5** , and i tryed to put my new folder with classes in autoloader, and nothing happens. PLease help me. I will post a piece of composer.json, to see how everything looks like.

**Compose.json file**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
                        "app/Repositories              
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"

        }
```

This is the part where i putted my new folder "Repositories", but nothing happens, also i dumped the autloader to load clases but still nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to issue `composer dump-autoload` command to regenerate the vendor/autoload.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add directories that are under `app/`. Just use `psr-4` and namespace the classes in that folder like:

```
directory app/Repositories
namespace App\Repositories;
```

Comment: I tryed that, but still no solution.

Comment: @VeskoVujovic What do you mean by no solution? You don't add anything to `composer.json`, remove that part you added, and just run `composer dump-autoload`  - it will work, trust me.

Comment: I know everything you say, but it doesn't work. When you type App\R it only displays deafult folders of laravel5.... He don't see any folder i create.

Comment: What do you mean by `He`? Check your IDE settings, it's not composer's thing.

Comment: Composer doesn't see any new folder i create under my app directory

Answer (score 0):

Create app/YourFolder and set namespace YourNamespace\YourFolder; to all files under that folder